# Discrepancy in iCloud backup sizes

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud, backup

After recently deciding to try out iCloud backups on my iPhone 4S and iPad 2 (both on iOS 5.0.1), I ran into a problem that's making it difficult to trust these backups. The "Latest Backup" for each device never goes higher than 2.0 GB, while the "Next Backup Size" is reported as a higher number — 6.3 GB in the case of my iPhone. This next backup size matches what iCloud generally matches the cloud space reportedly occupied by the iPhone backup. This problem persists no matter how many times I delete and re-back up each device. If I turn off components of the backup (photos, for example, which is the largest item on my iPhone), then the total backup drops below 2 GB and starts to match up. So, questions:

- Is anyone else seeing this behavior?
- Does anyone have a "Latest Backup" larger than 2 GB, and therefore not seeing this problem? If so, what device and iOS version are you running?
- Has anyone with this problem successfully restored from an iCloud backup? Or unsuccessfully, for that matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue appears to have been solved with the iOS 5.1 update.